# Local DNS using Bind9

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind, hostname

I have a few computers on my home network that I would like to assign names to. I don't want them to be a TLD, just aliases, like "orange" or something. The tutorials that I was reading such as [this](http://www.servermom.org/how-to-install-and-setup-bind9-on-ubuntu-server/136/) one, were all using `ns1.sometld.com`,etc. I don't want to have to use an external server. I simply want to bind something like this:

`orange` `192.168.1.2`

`banana` `192.168.1.7`

etc, etc.

Any resources on how to do this would be awesome!

EDIT: I'm using Ubuntu 14.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need DNS:

The most trivial solution is to simply distribute a [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) to all your computers:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.1.2 orange 
192.168.1.7 banana
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! And if for some reason I wanted to use this in Windows, is there a similar config?

Comment: file is under `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Same syntax as in `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

In BIND (an probably any DNS server), you need to work at least with something like `orange.domain` or `orange.sometld.com`

If you configure your computers to use the `sometld.com` suffix [(see here for details for setting them in windows)](http://support.simpledns.com/kb/a138/how-to-configure-dns-suffixes-on-windows-vista2008.aspx), you will be able just to type the left part of the names in any program.

In linux you can edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and add the line `domain sometld.com` for the same results

Comment: Thanks! I should've mentioned this earlier, but I'm using Ubuntu. See edit.

Comment: You can create a zone for the root, `.`; you don't have to have a TLD.  However, this may put you in conflict with the internet root.

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler solution than distributing `/etc/hosts` files is to install the [`avahi-daemon` package](https://launchpad.net/avahi).  Then you can access all your hosts as `orange.local` and `banana.local`, etc.

For Windows, there is an implementation of by Apple called “[Bonjour](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999)”.  (The download is called “*Bonjour Print Services*”, but don’t let that fool you, it really is a general implementation of the same thing as Avahi.)